# Plotting Stackbar chart in Seaborn for showing clustering

Tags: python, pandas, matplotlib, seaborn

Here is my data where I have Wines%, Fruits%, etc which sums up to 1 and is based on the Total_Spent column. There's also a cluster columns that you can see:

[image]

Now, I want to show a stacked bar chart where on the x axis I'll have the clusters and the vertical stacked bar will be all the wines%, meat%, etc for every cluster. Using this chart, I'll be able to observe which cluster is spending what percent of their money on which product. I'm trying to use **seaborn** for this. Can anyone help me in figuring out a way to plot this stacked bar plot?

**Update**

So I have written this code to get the data in the correct format:

```
df_test = df[['Wines%', 'Fruits%', 'Meat%', 'Fish%', 'Sweets%','Gold%', 'Clusters']]
df_unpivoted = df_test.melt(id_vars=['Clusters'], var_name='Category', value_name='Spend%')
df_unpivoted.head()
df_new = pd.pivot_table(df_unpivoted, index=['Clusters','Category'])
```

And the dataframe looks like this:

[image]

How can I achieve the same result with this dataframe now?

Comment: Just help me on plotting the chart now using seaborn

Comment: Please, please, add the test data as text, never as image.

Comment: What about `sns.histplot(data=df_new.reset_index(), x='Clusters', weights='spend%', hue='Category', multiple='fill', discrete=True)`? Note that you seem to be weighting all the original rows equally, independent of `total_spent`.

Comment: Hi Johan, I got the solution earlier itself and had written the draft but forgot to post it. You'll find my answer below. Thanks for your help anyway

Comment: And yes, I can try histplot and see how it looks lile

Comment: **[Don't Post Screenshots](https://meta.stackoverflow.com/questions/303812/)**. This question needs a [SSCCE](http://sscce.org/). Always provide a [mre], with **code, data, errors, current output, and expected output, as [formatted text](https://stackoverflow.com/help/formatting)**. It's likely the question will be down-voted and closed. You're discouraging assistance, as no one wants to retype data/code, and screenshots are often illegible. [edit] the question and **add text**. Plots are okay. See [How to provide a reproducible dataframe](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/52413246).

Comment: I have added the code already along with the screenshot, don't really understand why it has been downvoted.

Answer (score -1, accepted):

Ok, I achieved the solution with this:

```
df_test = df[['Wines%', 'Fruits%', 'Meat%', 'Fish%', 'Sweets%','Gold%', 'Clusters']]
df_unpivoted = df_test.melt(id_vars=['Clusters'], var_name='Category', value_name='Spend%')
df_unpivoted.head()
df_new = pd.pivot_table(df_unpivoted, index=['Clusters','Category'])
df_new = df_new.reset_index(level=[0,1])
sns.barplot(x='Clusters',y='Spend%', hue='Category', data=df_new)
```

I had to change the multi-index column to a single index column with the reset_index code and then just plot it using barplot.

Comment: You have unnecessary code: (1) `cols = ['Wines%', 'Fruits%', 'Meat%', 'Fish%', 'Sweets%','Gold%', 'Clusters']` (2) `dfm = df_test[cols].melt(id_vars='Clusters', var_name='Cat', value_name='Spend%')` (3) `p = sns.barplot(data=dfm, x='Clusters', y='Spend%', hue='Cat')`